# After End of Evangelion, does Gendo's soul end up residing in EVA-01 with Yui?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

After End of Evangelion, does Gendo's soul end up residing in EVA-01 with Yui? Was there anyone else in there too? At the end of the movie, Gendo ends up being eaten by EVA-01, but he doesn't turn into the orange LCL like the others, I was wondering if it meant that his soul ended up being trapped inside EVA-01 instead, or if it didn't have any particular meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't stated, but he is killed by EVA-01 so he died before he could be sent into the Human Instrumentality Project, or his soul could of been taken into EVA-01 when he was killed, there just isn't enough information to go off.